# What does [ref] do in a VCL application?

Tags: delphi, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference, custom-attributes

I'm working on a VCL application with Delphi 10 Seattle, and created a TDBGrid event handler via the IDE when I noticed that Delphi added a `Ref` custom attribute for the `Rect` argument:

```
procedure TfrmXxx.yyyDrawColumnCell(Sender: TObject;
  const [Ref] Rect: TRect; DataCol: Integer; Column: TColumn;
  State: TGridDrawState);
begin
  //
end;
```

- When or why does the IDE decide to insert this?
- Does it have any effect in a VCL app?

---

**update**

Here's a video for those who cannot reproduce the behavior:
[image]

Comment: As to when Delphi decides to add it to your event handler: I'd guess when the event handler method signature uses it.

Comment: Note that `ref` has nothing to do with VCL/FMX or Intel/Arm. if a parameter is marked `const [ref]` it just means that a pointer to that parameter will be passed (i.e. pass by reference) and not the actual value.

Comment: @TOndrej: I don't see the attribute in the signature of `VCL.DBGrids.TDrawColumnCellEvent`...

Comment: @WoutervanNifterick In that case, I was guessing wrong. ;-)

Comment: Interesting - I cannot reproduce this behavior.

Comment: @UweRaabe: I've added a video to demonstrate what happens here. I've started with a new, empty VCL project.

Comment: Don't get me wrong - I did believe you in the first place. The question is, why doesn't it happen in my installation?

Comment: JFTR, I have Seattle Subscription Update 1  installed.

Comment: I don't have update 1 installed yet. I only have compiler speed and IDE fix pack installed at the moment (I usually also install cnpack, but I don't have it in this case)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is mentioned in the docs:

> Constant parameters may be passed to the function by value or by reference, depending on the specific compiler used. To force the compiler to pass a constant parameter by reference, you can use the [Ref] decorator with the const keyword.

See [Constant Parameters](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Parameters_(Delphi)#Constant_Parameters)

> When or why does the IDE decide to insert this?

The IDE never inserts this. It just copies the declaration of the event handler. Whoever wrote the event handler put the pass by`[ref]`erence marker in there.

> Does it have any effect in a VCL app?

Yes.
If you mark a 8 byte parameter as const it will normally get passed by value in x64 and passed by reference in x86.
Declaring it as `const [ref]` will force it to be passed by reference in both cases.
It is very useful when doing inline assembly and in multi-threaded code.
Before `const [ref]` was introduced we were forced to use `var` instead of `const` to achieve the same effect.

Comment: The TRect being 16-bytes in size probably would get passed by ref anyway.

Comment: The IDE *does* insert this custom attribute when you create the handler by doubleclicking in the object inspector. Try it. The event itself is defined like this: `TDrawColumnCellEvent = procedure (Sender: TObject; const Rect: TRect;
    DataCol: Integer; Column: TColumn; State: TGridDrawState) of object;
  `  (without the custom attribute).

Comment: My next guess would be that the win32 compiler includes the [ref] attribute in the method RTTI by default and that's where the IDE pulls it from.

Comment: Marco Cantu states: "Finally there is a fairly unknown option for passing an object as parameter, called constant reference and written as [ref] const. When a parameter is passed as constant reference it behaves similarly to a passing by reference (var), but it allows more flexibility in the type of the parameter you are passing, not requiring an exact type match (as passing an object of a subclass is allowed)." – 

--------- So, [ref] has a double purpose.